# Clarification on how setTimeout & forloop interaction works

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, settimeout

I am having trouble understanding why the answer is 9. From my understanding adding the `setTimeout` function into a for loop means that the `setTimeout` function will run 3 times for each loop. So it loops 3 times and in each loop, `setTimeout` runs 3 times for a total of 9 times? I am missing the understanding.

```js
var result = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    result += i;
  }, 1000);
}

console.log(result) // answer is 9
```

Comment: I get `0`  in the snippet I made you because setTimeout returns immediately. You might want to use a closure

Comment: setTimeout() is a async function and you want result at different times. Value will change on time to time.

Comment: Because of [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1451009) - `i` is always going to be `3` when the callback executes, so `3 + 3 + 3 = 9`

Comment: You  need to study and understand async and sync functions.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a single-thread system. `setTimeout` basically puts your request on the call stack to be executed after 1 second.
It is still fired in the scope of your function, but at the end of it, with a 1 second delay.
At the end of your function, `i === 3` and because you execute it 3 times, you'll get `result === 9`

You can see this more clearly if you do this:

```js
var result = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    result += i;
    console.log("i: " + i);
    console.log("result: " + result)
  }, 1000);
}
```

You can wrap up your timeout, to break the dependency on `i`.
Do this by placing `setTimeout` in a function and pass `i` into it. that way, it doesn't matter what `i` is,
as we are using `j` which is scoped inside the new function.

```js
var result = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  (function(j){ 
    setTimeout(function() {
      result += j;
      console.log("i: " + i);
      console.log("j: " + j);
      console.log("result: " + result)
    }, 1000);
  })(i);
}
```